# generate printable bank giro deposit slip

Tags: pdf-generation, bank

I am trying to generate a Bank Deposit slip (ideally a PDF) with incremental serial numbers everytime someone clicks and downloads one. Now I know how to generate PDFs etc programmatically but I wonder if there is a 'best practice' way to do this kinda thing before I start generating this deposit slip pixel by pixel on a PDF? There must be some templates out there I can use?

Any ideas on what approach to be followed in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is a kind of thing that evolves your invoice system, customers (if you have one), products/services that you are negociating, and of course a place in a database to save all your transactions.

I was staked in Bank Slip, but now I found a simple solution, I'm going to share here with you, perhapes is not the best solution, but apparently was good to me, actually I'm building this.

I'll talk here about the structure to accomodate the transactions datas, here I go:

A table in your database, I had called it **bank_slip**

here goes the fields for **bank_slip**

**`id | invoice_number | transferor | code_transferor | amount_title | due_date | our_number | drawee | fines`**

Now I will explain the process to generate a bank slip »» 
I supose that you have already an invoice system working in your system and it must be integrated with your customers and products/services of course. 
Once you have invoice, customer and products/services you can start to work in your bank slip.

In the invoice system you need to call the bank slip. Why there? 'cause there you have all the necessarie information to generate your bank slip such as the struct of your **table bank_slip** showed above. You will pass all the information of your customer, service and invoice  across pages via form (POST or GET).

Then you need some class to generate the bank slip for you. I'm using this one --- http://www.boletophp.com.br/#download

The class was built to work with the mainly banks of Brazil, but of course you will need to find something that fits in your country, I think it is not the worst part of the job.

The worst for me was to integrate it to my system already in use and working, but like I explained above it fit like a gloves to me.

I hope you can find a solution to your problem.